# How to get column value into row header

Tags: sql

```
ID    Amount      Date
------------------------------
 1    300     02-02-2010 00:00
 2    400     02-02-2009 00:00
 3    200     02-02-2011 00:00
 4    300     22-02-2010 00:00
 5    400     12-02-2009 00:00
 6    500     22-02-2009 00:00
 7    600     02-02-2006 00:00
 8    700     02-07-2012 00:00
 9    500     08-02-2012 00:00
10    800     09-02-2011 00:00
11    500     06-02-2010 00:00
12    600     01-02-2011 00:00
13    300     02-02-2019 00:00
```

Desired output:

```
   Y1          Y2            Y3 ...........
 sum(amount)   sum(amount)   sum(amount)
```

What is an approach, where Y1 is the year part of the date, such that the result column would be the following?

```
 2006   2009    2010   2011   2012
 ---------------------------------
  600   1300     800   1900   1200
```

Database system: SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [dynamic `PIVOT` Table](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-dynamic-pivot-table-example-code.aspx)

```
DECLARE @Years nvarchar(max)
SELECT @Years =
  STUFF(
  (
    select distinct ',[' + cast(Year([date]) as nvarchar(4)) + ']'
    from YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE
    for xml path('')
  ),
  1,1,'')

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SELECT @SQL = N'
select
  *
from (
  select
    amount, year([date]) as [y]
  from YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE
) Data
PIVOT (
  sum(amount)
  FOR [y]
  IN (
    ' + @Years + '
  )
) PivotTable
'

EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

Reference: [`PIVOT` Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: This seems to be a little complex. I am not aware about the xml path. Can some one make a little easy for me.

Comment: @DharmendraMohapatra, The first `select` creates a variable named `years` that has `[2009],[2010],[2011]` etc (*it creates a string that is made by the distinct years in your table*).
We do this because that is the syntax required by the `PIVOT` command which we use in the second part of the query.  ([*MSDN `FOR XML`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx))

Comment: @ Gaby aka G. Petrioli,  Thanks

Comment: Does it work for multiple column.? example if I have another column called 'unit' after ID column then I need to add up the units too.

Comment: @DharmendraMohapatra, can you describe the resulting set ?

Comment: updated table 
ID    Amount      Date         Units
------------------------------
 1    300     02-02-2010 00:00  10
 2    400     02-02-2009 00:00  20
 3    200     02-02-2011 00:00  30 
 4    300     22-02-2010 00:00  40
 5    400     12-02-2009 00:00  50
 6    500     22-02-2009 00:00  20
 ..........................so on
Sample Desired Result

 YEAR           2006   2009    2010   2011   2012
               
 Total          600    1300     800   1900   1200

 Units_Total    10     100      90     80     40

Comment: @ Gaby aka G. Petrioli, Basically I need another aggregate row like the total amount under the header of year column.

Comment: @DharmendraMohapatra, if you want a new row you will need to `UNION` two PIVOT tables.. see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09491/1 for a working version of the code..

Comment: Thanks a ton It helped. I will come up few more questions but for the time being thanks a lot.

Comment: @DharmendraMohapatra no problem.. You can upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted, if you consider that it helped you or solved your question.. (*see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work*)

Comment: @ Gaby aka G. Petrioli,What if I am passing a value in the above code
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SELECT @SQL=N'
select
  *
from (
select amount, year([date]) as [y]
from YOUR_TABLE WHERE MID='+@MID+'
)Data
PIVOT (
  sum(amount)
  FOR [y]
  IN (
    '+@Years+'
)) PivotTable
'
MID is a nvarchar column in the table
I have added a extra where caluse which comes from the IN parameter in the store procedure. This gives me an error
"Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Sidebottom - 22345' to data type int"
Basically 'Sidebottom-22345' is a value in the MID field
Please help out

Comment: We are building dynamically a astring .. And string literals must be included in quotes, so you need to wrap the value in quotes (and it is always a good idea to put `[]` around names.. change `WHERE MID='+@MID+' )` to `WHERE [MID]='''+@MID+''' )`

Comment: How do I pass or compare a date like date > getdate()  or date = CAST(getdate() as date) to include it in the string

Comment: @ Gaby aka G. Petrioli,

SELECT @sql='

select 
    *
from (
    select ''Ongoing'' AS Ongoing,
    Coalesce(COUNT(project),0) AS project, Coalesce(COUNT(year(u.PlannedStartDate)),0) as [y]
    from Projects u  WHERE 
    u.actualstartdate IS  NULL 
    AND u.Startdate < ''+GETDATE()+''
    AND ID ='''+@ID+'''  
   
  ) Data
PIVOT (
  COUNT(project)
  FOR [y]
  IN (
    ' + @Years + '
  )
) PivotTable
'

Here I want to pass the cur date but it's not working..
this is because the value of GETDATE() is not coming in the string

Comment: @DharmendraMohapatra, since `GETDATE()` is a SQL function you can use it in the string directly, without using each value.. It will be executed when you execute the whole query.. so try `u.Startdate < GETDATE() AND ...`